i can't find the error in my c program for the data structure project
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct subNode{
    struct subNode*prev;
    struct subNode*next;
    char towns[50];
    int population;
};

struct mainNode{
    char districts[50];
    struct subNode*towns;
    struct mainNode*prev;
    struct mainNode*next;
};

struct binsNode{
    char districts[50];
    struct binsNode*next;
};


char Strings[400][50];
int counter =0;
int isRead =0;
int isSorted1=0;
int isSorted2=0;

struct mainNode*creatDistrictNode(char district[]){
    struct mainNode* newNode= (struct mainNode*) malloc(sizeof (struct mainNode));
    strcpy(newNode->districts, district);
    newNode->towns= NULL;
    newNode->next= NULL;
    newNode->prev= NULL;
    return newNode;
}


void addTown(struct mainNode*district, char towns[], int population){
    struct subNode*newNode= (struct subNode*) malloc(sizeof (struct subNode));
    struct subNode*last= district->towns;

    strcpy(newNode->towns, towns);
    newNode->population= population;

    if(!district->towns){
        newNode->next= NULL;
        newNode->prev= NULL;
        district->towns= newNode;
        return;
    }

    while (last->next){
        last=last->next;
    }
    last->next= newNode;
    newNode->prev= last;
    newNode->next= NULL;
}

void addDistrict(struct mainNode**head, char districts[]){
    struct mainNode*newNode= creatDistrictNode(districts);
    struct mainNode*last= *head;

    if(!*head){
        *head= newNode;
        return;
    }
    while (last->next){
        last=last->next;
    }
    last->next= newNode;
    newNode->prev= last;

    char *token = strtok(districts , "|");
    while (token) {
        int population = atoi(strtok(NULL, "|"));
        char town[50];
        strcpy(town, token);
        addTown(newNode, town, population);
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
    }
}

void removeDuplicates(struct mainNode *head) {
    struct mainNode *current = head->next;

    while (current) {
        struct mainNode *runner = current->next;

        while (runner) {
            if (strcmp(current->districts, runner->districts) == 0) {
                // Duplicate found, remove runner node
                struct mainNode *temp = runner;
                runner->prev->next = runner->next;
                if (runner->next) {
                    runner->next->prev = runner->prev;
                }
                runner = runner->next;
                free(temp);
            } else {
                runner = runner->next;
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int getMax(struct mainNode* head) {
    struct mainNode* temp = head->next;
    int maxLength = 0;
    while (temp) {
        int length = strlen( temp->districts);
        if (length > maxLength) {
            maxLength = length;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return maxLength;
}

void initializeBins(struct binsNode** bins, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bins[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void insertBins(struct binsNode** bins, char *str, int index){
    int binIndex= tolower(str[index]) -'a';
    struct binsNode* temp= (struct binsNode*) malloc(sizeof (struct binsNode));
    strcpy(temp->districts, str);
    temp->next= NULL;
    if(!bins[index])
        bins[index]= temp;

    else{
        struct binsNode*p= bins[index];
        while (p->next){
            p=p->next;
        }

        p->next= temp;
    }
}

char* removeBins(struct binsNode** bins, int index){
    struct binsNode*temp= bins[index];
    bins[index]= bins[index]->next;
    char*str= temp->districts;
    free(temp);
    return str;
}

void radixSort(struct mainNode** head){
    int maxDigit= getMax(*head);
    struct binsNode**bins= (struct binsNode*) malloc(27*sizeof (struct binsNode));

    for (int i = 0; i < 27; ++i) {
        bins[i]= malloc(sizeof (struct binsNode));
        bins[i]->next= NULL;
    }
    initializeBins(bins, 27);
    for (int i = 0; i < maxDigit; i++) {
        struct mainNode*temp= (*head)->next;
        while (temp){
            insertBins(bins, temp->districts, i);
            temp= temp->next;
        }
        struct mainNode*tempHead= creatDistrictNode("");
        struct mainNode*tailHead= tempHead;

        for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++) {

            while (bins[j]){
                char*district= removeBins(bins, j);
                struct mainNode*tempNode= creatDistrictNode(district);
                tailHead->next= tempNode;
                tempNode->prev= tailHead;
                tailHead= tempNode;
            }
        }
        tailHead->next= NULL;
        *head= tempHead->next;
        free(tempHead);
        initializeBins(bins, 27);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        struct binsNode* current = bins[i];
        while (current) {
            struct binsNode* temp = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }

    free(bins);
}


void display(struct mainNode*head){
    struct mainNode*districts=head;
    while (districts){
        printf("%s: \n", districts->districts);
        struct subNode*town= districts->towns;
        while (town){
            printf("%s\t", town->towns);
            printf("%d\n", town->population);
            town= town->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
        districts=districts->next;
    }
}

void displayMenu(){
    printf("please choose an operation from <1-14>\n");
    printf("1. Load the input file\n");
    printf("2. Print the loaded information before sorting\n");
    printf("3. Sort the districts alphabetically\n");
    printf("4. Sort the towns for each district based on population in ascending order\n");
    printf("5. Print the sorted information\n");
    printf("6. Add a new district to the list\n");
    printf("7. Add a new town to a certain district\n");
    printf("8. Delete a town from a specific district\n");
    printf("9. Delete a complete district\n");
    printf("10. Calculate the population of Palestine, the max and min town population\n");
    printf("11. Print the districts and their total population\n");
    printf("12. Change the population of a town\n");
    printf("13. Save to output file\n");
    printf("14. Exit\n");
}
int main() {
    struct mainNode* head = (struct mainNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct mainNode));
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    head->next=NULL;
    head->prev= NULL;
    head->towns= NULL;



    int operationNumber;

    do {
        displayMenu();
        scanf("%d", &operationNumber);

        switch (operationNumber) {

            case 1:
                if (isRead == 1) {
                    printf("the input file haas already been loaded! choose another operation\n\n");
                    break;
                }
                FILE *in;
                in = fopen("districts.txt", "r");
                char array[100];
                char tokens[3][30];

                int i = 0;

                while (fgets(array, sizeof(array) /sizeof (char), in)) {

                    strcpy(Strings[i], array);

                    int j=0;
                    char *token= strtok(array, "|");

                    while (token && j<3){

                        strcpy(tokens[j], token);
                        token= strtok(NULL, "|");
                        j++;

                    }

                struct mainNode* newDistrict = creatDistrictNode(tokens[0]);
                    addDistrict(&head, tokens[0]);

                    char *townToken = strtok(tokens[1], " ");
                    while (townToken) {
                        int population = atoi(tokens[2]);
                        addTown(newDistrict, townToken, population);
                        townToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
                    }

                    i++;
                }
                counter = i;
                isRead=1;

                fclose(in);


                break;


            case 2:
                if (isRead) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

                        printf("%s\n", Strings[i]);}

                } else {

                    printf("please load the input file first\n\n");

                    continue;
                }
                break;


            case 3:
                if(isRead){
                removeDuplicates(head);
                radixSort(&head);
                printf("districts sorted successfully\n\n");
                isSorted1=1;
                }

                else{
                    printf("please load the input file first\n\n");
                    continue;
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                if(isRead){
                isSorted2=0;
                }
                else{
                    printf("please load the input file first\n\n");
                    continue;
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                if(isRead){
                    if(isSorted1 && isSorted2){
                        display(head->next);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("the information are not sorted!\n\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                else{
                    printf("please load the input file first\n\n");
                    continue;
                }
                break;

            case 6:
                break;

            case 7:
                break;

            case 8:
                break;

            case 9:
                break;

            case 10:
                break;

            case 11:
                break;

            case 12:
                break;

            case 13:
                break;

            default:
                if (operationNumber == 14)
                    continue;
                printf("No such operation! please try again\n");
        }


    } while (operationNumber != 14);
    return 0;
}



here's the full code of my program in c
the program is supposed to read from a file districts and towns and their population and store them in a doubly linked lists each district has it's own towns and populations and here's the file:
Hebron | Dura | 100000
Hebron | Halhul | 40000
Jenin | Jaba | 7000
Jenin | Yabad | 31000
Jenin | Jenin | 92000
Gaza | Jabalia | 20000
Gaza | BeitHanoon | 50000
Salfeet | Deristya | 4000
Salfeet | hares | 7000

and i have 14 cases to do the first one to load the input file and the second one to print the input file
the third one is to sort the districts alphabatically using only radix sort, and the 5th is print the sorted information, however when i try and sort the districts and press 3 the program stops working and exists : Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
i believe there's a problem in linking every town to its own district and also there's a problem in the radix sort that i can't find even using gpt
i tried to see if i have pointer that's allocated and i'm using and it didn't change anything

Does struct binsNode**bins= (struct binsNode*) malloc(27*sizeof (struct binsNode)); look correct to you?

Don't cast void *.  Prefer using the variable instead of the type for sizeof, i.e. binNode **bins = malloc(sizeof *bins * 27)`.  Use symbolic constant instead of a magic values (27 etc).

Instead of dumping all your code here you should put some effort into making it a [mre].  Hard-coding a failing test case is a particular powerful way to demonstrate the issue. Failing that as your program is interactive you also have to tell us what input you provided at run-time. It will help you focus where the problem is and makes it easier for us to help you.

strcopy() will cause a buffer overflow if strlen(towns)+1 > sizeof newNode->towns.

Always check return values otherwise you are wasting your time.  Especially for I/O operations like fopen().

Prefer strtol() to atoi() as the latter doesn't have a way to reliably signal errors.

Program segfaults for me in addDistrict().

Avoid global variables.

Why do you plural names towns and districts in struct subNode and struct mainNode?

Question: Apart from an exercise dancing near the edge, what is the perceived advantage of using double-linked lists instead of much simpler single-linked lists?

@Fe2O3 It's in the project Requirements to use doubly linked lists

@MohammadAbuHijleh Okay. A reasonable challenge to gain experience with DLLs. Perhaps the pedagogical objective is for you to finish, then look over the code and realise that ->prev acted as little more than a troublesome "appendix" and was an irrelevant liability. Best wishes...

@MohammadAbuHijleh Consider isolating DLL requirements from payload requirements for your two DLLs. Manipulating a particular node (its place in its "chain") can be made somewhat generic, allowing the code manipulating each datatype ("struct") to re-use functions. (Imagine a dataset of several more layers; more that the "district" and "town" used here.) Can you see a solution that avoids replication (copy/paste/adapt) of insert(), extract() and, possibly swap() functions? Less code = better testing and less that can go wrong.

@Fe2O3 i see what your idea i'll consider doing it after i finish with the project requirements thank you for the advice

so when i remove the duplicates and sort the districts where does the towns go? and what should i do to add every town to its own district after i remove the duplicates and sorry for asking so many questions@AllanWind
